# Wordpress meta data is written on top of page instead of the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-fields

i'm building a wordpress webpage based on the Skeleton Wordpress theme.

I have 2 posts showing on a page and each of these posts have custom fields values (meta data). Im using the shortcode from the skeleton theme to get a post-feed from a specific category and in that loop i have inserted this tag that displays the custom fields data

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

I am getting the data - but the problem is, the data is shown on TOP of the page instead of inside the  in the post.

What could've ive possibly done wrong? or is it something with skeleton i am doing wrong?

**Webpage** : http://visbyfangelse.se.preview.binero.se/rum-priser-preview/

as you can see two posts are shown - and the meta data is shown on the top of the page.

**Code to the loop** : http://pastebin.com/mRQY5GNz
As you can see i want the meta displayed in the div which i assigned this class to "my_room_meta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the_meta() echos the results to the page, you could make your own replacement function:

```
function get_the_meta() {
        if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
                $output="<ul class='post-meta'>\n";
                foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
                        $keyt = trim($key);
                        if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
                                continue;
                        $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
                        $value = implode($values,', ');
                        $output.= apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);
                }
                return $output . "</ul>\n";
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Meaning i put this function in functions.php and instead of calling the_meta in the loop i just call get_the_meta() which is the name of the function ive added?

Comment: I would put this function and any other code that isn't already part of wordpresses core in your own plugin to ensure that when you upgrade wordpress they don't get wiped out..... but yes

Comment: Dang dude! it works like a charm! you saved my day!

Big thanks!

Comment: glad to help:) remember to accept the answer if it worked for you;)